# Analyze CSV data in R

Tags: r, csv

I have CSV data as follows:

```
 code, label, value
 ABC,  len,   10
 ABC,  count, 20
 ABC,  data,  102
 ABC,  data,  212
 ABC,  data,  443
 ...
 XYZ,  len,   11
 XYZ,  count, 25
 XYZ,  data,  782
 ...
```

The number of `data` entries is different for each `code`. (This doesn't matter for my question; I'm just point it out.)

I need to analyze the `data` entries for each `code`. This would include calculating the median, plotting graphs, etc. This means I should separate out the `data` for each `code` and make it numeric?

Is there a better way of doing this than this kind of thing:

```
 x = read.csv('dataFile.csv, header=T)
 ...
 median(as.numeric(subset(x, x$code=='ABC' & x$label=='data')$value))
 boxplot(median(as.numeric(subset(x, x$code=='ABC' & x$label=='data')$value)))
```

Comment: R has many different "group" or "apply" type functions. See this question to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega

Answer (score 1):

`split` and `list2env` allows you to separate your data.frame `x` for each `code` generating one data.frame for each level in `code`:

```
list2env(split(x, x$code), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

or just

```
my.list <- split(x, x$code)
```

if you prefer to work with lists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand the final objective of your question, do you just want some pointers of what you could do it? because there are a lot of possible solutions.

When you ask: I need to analyze the data entries for each code. This would include calculating the median, plotting graphs, etc. This means I should separate out the data for each code and make it numeric?

The answer would be no, you don't strictly have to. You could use R functions which does this task for you, for example:

```
x = read.csv('dataFile.csv', header=T)

#is it numeric?
class(x$value)
# if it is already numeric you shouldn't have to convert it,
# if it strictly numeric I don't know any reason why it 
# should be read as strings but it happens.

aggregate(x,by=list(x$code),FUN="median")

boxplot(value~code,data=x)
# and you can do ?boxplot to look into its options.
```

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for suggestions/pointers as to how to easily work with the data structure.